# Javascript and Html custom cacluation not printing results correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to javascript and know basic HTML stuff from just hobby coding, and recently a friend approached me to try my hand at something written in javascript which... sounded easy at first but now that I'm down the rabbit hole I realize this is far more complicated than I anticipated. Can anyone give me insight into my code and tell me what I may be doing wrong etc? As far as I can tell it's correct? Yet it doesn't print the results, nothing even incorrectly either, just nothing. It's supposed to have 4 different functions for different calculations, but currently, there is only the first one that I've tried to get to produce anything to even give me an inkling of what's wrong but it appears I'm a bit too green to figure it out?

Edit: Thanks to the helpful comments fixing those errors now causes it to print results, however, it does seem some of the math might be broken, but I am concerned about the checkbox actually working? Does that look right?

```
<div id="calculator">
<span id="calcActive" class="wildPokemon"> <b>Select Encounter Type:</b><br> <select class="forminput" id="calc_select" onChange="switchCalc()" style="margin-bottom: 10px;text-align:center;">
  
          <option selected="selected" value="wildPokemon">Wild Pokemon</option>
          <option value="trainerBattle">Trainer/Social</option>
          <option value="officialWin">Official Battle Win</option>
          <option value="officialLoss">Official Battle Loss</option>
        </select>
<input type="checkbox" id="xpShare" name="xpShare" value="xpShare">
<label for="xpShare">XP Share</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="luckyEgg" name="luckyEgg" value="luckyEgg">
<label for="luckyEgg">Lucky Egg</label><br>
        </span><br>
 <div id="calc-desc">
 <p>Enter your current level, Current XP, and new XP to add in. The new level and new remaining XP will be displayed.</p><p><b>Your Level:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="1" max="100" onKeyUp="inputFullLevel(this, this.value)" id="currentLevel"><br> <b>Current XP:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="0" max="17820" onKeyUp="inputSpareXp(this, this.value)" id="currentXp"><br><b>New XP:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="1" max="17820" onKeyUp="inputXp(this, this.value)" id="newXp"></p><button class="forminput" type="button" onclick="runWildPokemon()">Calculate</button>

  </div><p>
  
  </p>
 
 <div id="calc-results">

 </div>
</div>

<script>
var xpToLevel = [180, 360, 540, 720, 900, 1080, 1260, 1440, 1620, 1800, 1980, 2160, 2340, 2520, 2700, 2880, 3060, 3240, 3420, 3600, 3780, 3960, 4140, 4320, 4500, 4680, 4860, 5040, 5220, 5400, 5580, 5760, 5940, 6120, 6300, 6480, 6660, 6840, 7020, 7200, 7380, 7560, 7740, 7920, 8100, 8280, 8460, 8820, 9000, 9180, 9360, 9540, 9720, 9900, 10080, 10260, 10440, 10620, 10800, 10980, 11160, 11340, 11520, 11700, 11880, 12060, 12240, 12600, 12780, 12960, 13140, 13320, 13500, 13680, 13860, 14040, 14220, 14400, 14580, 14760, 14940, 15120, 15300, 15480, 15660, 15840, 15660, 15840, 16020, 16200, 16380, 16560, 16740, 16920, 17100, 17280, 17460, 17540, 17820
],
xpToNext,
newXp,
currentLevel,
currentXp,
currentSpareXp,
goalLevel,
levelBaseXp,
nextLevelXp,
totalXp, 
spareXp,
xpToGoal,
trainerBattle,
officialWin,
officialLoss,
wildPokemon = '<p>Enter your current level, Current XP, and new XP to add in. The new level and new remaining XP will be displayed.</p><p><b>Your Level:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="1" max="100" onKeyUp="inputFullLevel(this, this.value)" id="currentlevel"><br> <b>Current XP:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="0" max="17820" onKeyUp="inputSpareXp(this, this.value)" id="currentXp"><br><b>New XP:</b> <input class="forminput" type="number" min="1" max="17820" onKeyUp="inputXp(this, this.value)" id="newXp"></p><button class="forminput" type="button" onclick="wildPokemon()">Calculate</button>';


   function switchCalc() {
      var c = document.getElementById("calc_select"),
        calcActive = c.options[c.selectedIndex].value;
      document.getElementById("calc-desc").innerHTML = eval(calcActive);
      document.getElementById("calc-results").innerHTML = '';
            }
    
  function runWildPokemon(){
    currentLevel = document.getElementById("currentLevel").value;
    currentXp = document.getElementById("currentXp").value;
    newXp = document.getElementById("newXp").value;
    const cb = document.getElementById('xpShare');
    const cb2 = document.getElementById('luckyEgg');
    console.log(cb.checked);
    xpToNext = xpToLevel[currentLevel - 1];
    newTotalXp = parseInt(newXp) * 0.5;
    
    if (document.getElementById("xpShare").checked == true) {
      newTotalXp *= 0.5;
    }
   
    if (document.getElementById("luckyEgg").checked == true) {
      newTotalXp *= 1.5;
    }

    while(currentXp >= xpToNext) {
      currentXp = currentXp - xpToNext;
      currentLevel = currentLevel + 1;
      xpToNext = xpToLevel[currentLevel - 1];
    }
    document.getElementById("calc-results").innerHTML = '<b>Level:</b> ' + currentLevel +'   <b>XP:</b> ' + '[' + newTotalXp + '/' + xpToNext + ']';
  }

        function inputXp(field, input) {
    if (input > 17820) {
    field.value = 17820;
    }
            if (input < 0) {
    field.value = 0;
        }
    }
        function inputSpareXp(field, input) {
        if (input > 17819) {
    field.value = 17819;
    }
            if (input < 0) {
    field.value = 0;
        }
    }
        function inputFullLevel(field, input) {
        if (input > 100) {
    field.value = 100;
    }
            if (input <= 0) {
    field.value = 1;
        }
    }
        function inputLevel(field, input) {
        if (input > 99) {
    field.value = 99;
    }
            if (input <= 0) {
    field.value = 1;
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
#calculator{
width: 300px;
background: var(--back1);
margin: auto;
padding: 10px;
border: 10px solid var(--outline);
}
</style>
```

Comment: You redeclare one variable again as a function: `wildPokemon`. This will make the previous assignment void.

Comment: You have a variable and a function with same name: `wildPokemon`. You declare a `const` (`cb`) after it has already been declared (`const`s can't be redeclared); and you mispelled `newXp` into `newXP`. After that it prints [`false`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/vfxp9be5/). Is that what you're expecting?
As an advice: make smaller steps and use the browser console. When your script has an error, it gives you useful info about that error. It tells you what's wrong (in most cases searching by the error text will provide sufficient explanation). Take your time.

Comment: @tao The plan with the checkboxes is to tell when they're checked, and when they aren't they're false then they multiple newXp by either .05 or 1.5

Comment: If you want to multiply `a` by `0.05` when condition `b` is `true` and by `1.5` when it's `false`, you can write it as a ternary: `a *= b ? .05 : 1.5;`